# AFNetworking sending NSDictionary as single array values instead of sending them as complete objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I'm trying to send a `NSArray *appData` as it is a `NSArray` that contains a `NSDictionary` (*See data layout below*) but when I receive the `Array` in `PHP` all the values in `NSDictionary` are sent as single Arrays and not in the same format they were sent (*See below PHP log data*).

All other values in `NSDictionary* params` are sent and received correctly.

Is this a bug or a problem in my code? if the later is the issue, What am i doing wrong?

Note: I am using the laster version of `AFNetworking`

**EDIT:**
As a result of `@dpassage` answer I edited to include a more extensive test and to send the information as `form-data`. The interesting thing around the test is that the `@"test"` param sent to the server is showing great in `PHP` but not the `@"share":appData` its very strange

```
- (void) checkForUploadEligibility {
   NSArray* dates = [myModel getStatsMaxAndMinResults];
    if ( dates ) {
        NSDictionary* d = [dates objectAtIndex:0];
        NSDate* minDate = d[@"minDate"];
        NSDate* maxDate = d[@"maxDate"];
        NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [maxDate timeIntervalSinceDate:minDate];

        int numberOfDays = secondsBetween / 86400;
        numberOfDays = abs(numberOfDays);

        if (numberOfDays >= 0) {
            myUser = [myModel getCurrentUser];
            if ( myUser.userWebID && myUser.authToken ) {
                NSArray* appData = [myModel getAllStatsData];
                if (!appData) {
                    return;
                }
                NSDictionary* params = @{  @"userID": myUser.userWebID,
                                       @"authCode": myUser.authToken,
                                       @"interact":@{@"action":@"uploadAppStats",
                                                     @"actionTarget":@"uploadAppStats"},
                                       @"share":appData,
                                       @"test":@[@{@"test1":@{@"test2":@"test2"}},@{@"test3":@"test3"}]
                                       };
                [myShare uploadStats:params statsData:appData];
            }

        }
    }
}
- (void) uploadStats:(NSDictionary*)params statsData:(NSArray *)statsData {
    NSLog(@"count %i, %@",[statsData count],statsData);
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:sysURL];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:url];

    NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:sysAppURLPath parameters:params];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){
                                                                                            NSLog(@"a: Inside the success block %@",JSON);
                                                                                            if ( [JSON objectForKey:@"ok"] ) {
                                                                                            //    [myModel deleteAllStatsData:statsData];
                                                                                            }

                                                                                        }
                                                                                        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){

                                                                                            NSLog(@"json text is: %@", JSON);
                                                                                            NSLog(@"Request failed with error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                                                                                        }];
    // Debug HTTP response
    BOOL dbug = YES;
    if (dbug) {
        [operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"HTTP r: %@",  operation.responseString);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"HTTP Error: %@",  operation.responseString);
        }
         ];
    }
    [operation start];

}
```

**Error log**

```
count 5, (
        {
        date = "2013-09-09 16:10:51 +0000";
        name = selectRoutine;
        shared = 0;
        timeSpent = 3;
    },
        {
        date = "2013-09-09 16:10:53 +0000";
        name = manageExercises;
        shared = 0;
        timeSpent = 1;
    }, // MORE.....



   HTTP Error: array(24) {
      multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
array(5) {
  ["authCode"]=>
  string(32) "e186cdd000a741ef76555009d7e86d80"
  ["interact"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["action"]=>
    string(14) "uploadAppStats"
    ["actionTarget"]=>
    string(14) "uploadAppStats"
  }
  ["share"]=>
  array(15) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(19) "2013-09-09 19:52:31"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "selectRoutine"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["timeSpent"]=>
      string(1) "3"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(19) "2013-09-09 19:52:33"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(14) "manageRoutines"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(1) {
      ["timeSpent"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(1) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(19) "2013-09-09 22:24:31"
    }
    [7]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "selectRoutine"
    }
    [8]=>
    array(1) {
      ["timeSpent"]=>
      string(2) "19"
    }
    [9]=>
    array(1) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(19) "2013-09-09 22:24:45"
    }
    [10]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(14) "manageRoutines"
    }
    [11]=>
    array(1) {
      ["timeSpent"]=>
      string(2) "14"
    }
    [12]=>
    array(1) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(19) "2013-09-09 22:25:58"
    }
    [13]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "manageExercises"
    }
    [14]=>
    array(1) {
      ["timeSpent"]=>
      string(2) "73"
    }
  }
  ["test"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["test1"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["test2"]=>
        string(5) "test2"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["test3"]=>
      string(5) "test3"
    }
  }
  ["userID"]=>
  string(24) "5224b598f86f265801000008"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem:**

`NSArray* appData` that is inserted into `@"share":appData` somehow is translated into a multitude of little arrays.

**The solution:**

Somehow if I insert a `NSArray` to the `Key-Value NSDictionary @"share"`  it doesn't work as expected. Then I went on changed that `NSArray` into a `NSDictionary` that didn't work either.

*What worked is the code below*. I had to recreate `NSArray* appData` as `NSDictionary* appData2`. Then I had to wrap what would be each individual `NSDictionary data object` into another  `NSDictionary` but I had to give this new object an **explicit numeric index**... After doing that it would then send the information correctly.

*I guess that my problem is a bug?* I don't really know... but if anyone has the problem too, this could help you.

```
        NSArray* appData = [myModel getAllStatsData];
        if (!appData) {
            return;
        }

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        NSMutableDictionary* choa = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        int i = 0;
        for (StatsAppUsage*statObj in appData) {

        [choa addEntriesFromDictionary:@{[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]:@{@"date":[dateFormat stringFromDate:statObj.date],
                                                          @"name":statObj.name,
                                                          @"timeSpent": statObj.timeSpent
                                                          }
                          }];
            i++;
        }
        NSDictionary* appData2 = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:choa];
        NSDictionary* params = @{  @"userID": myUser.userWebID,
                                   @"authCode": myUser.authToken,
                                   @"interact":@{@"action":@"uploadAppStats",
                                                 @"actionTarget":@"uploadAppStats"},
                                   @"share":appData2
                                   };
```

**@"share" PHP output**

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-09-09 19:52:31
            [name] => selectRoutine
            [timeSpent] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-09-09 19:52:33
            [name] => manageRoutines
            [timeSpent] => 2
        )
```

Comment: I just used this answer to solve my problem. thanks very much. one thing that got me stuck for some time even after I followed your solution was the necessary step of setting the parameter encoding to `AFFormURLParameterEncoding` instead of `AFJSONParameterEncoding`. Perhaps highlighting this somewhere in your answer will help future readers a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue comes about because you're using a default HTTP POST with arguments to send your value. You can confirm this by printing out the content-type of the post on the server side; it should be something along the lines of `x-www-form-urlencoded`. If that's the case, that data format can't really express arrays and dictionaries well.  So you get the odd format you're seeing on the server side.

What you probably want to do is send your data as JSON, not as plain form parameters. I believe the thing you want to do is set the `parameterEncoding` property of your `AFHTTPClient` to `AFJSONParameterEncoding`. This will send your request as JSON, which is capable of representing arrays and dictionaries correctly on the wire.

Comment: It says  when i do `print_r($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]);`  I get `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  But I modified the script to be `NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:sysAppURLPath parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        
    }];`  and now i get `multipart/form-data` but with the same error

Comment: Also I tried `httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;` and I can see the `CONTENT_TYPE` as `application/json` but i tried to var_dump($_REQUEST) and $_POST but both show empty