# AFNetworking 1.x post JSON to PHP

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to post a `NSArray` to my PHP web service and on the server side convert them to PHP arrays to update my db.

The below is the `NSLog` of the parameter I am sending.

```
params = (
      {
        param1 = 3;
        param2 = "string1";
        param3 = "2013-12-09";
      },
      {
        param1 = 3;
        param2 = "string1";
        param3 = "2013-12-09";
      }
);
```

However, on my PHP end when I do a `var_dump` I seem to be getting `NULL`.

**Objective-C code**

```
// mutable array to store all the dictionaries
NSMutableArray *mutableParameters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

for(Person *p in personArray) {
    NSMutableDictionary *personDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [personDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:p.id] forKey:@"param1"];
    [personDict setValue:p.strString forKey:@"param2"];
    [personDict setValue:p.strSelectedDate forKey:@"param3"];

    [mutableParameters addObject:personDict];
}

NSDictionary *parametersDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: mutableParameters, @"params", nil];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:WEBSERVICES_BASE_URL]];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

[httpClient postPath:@"clientEdit.php" parameters:parametersDict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // success
    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Request Successful, response '%@'", responseStr);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // failure
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

**PHP Code**

```
$params = $_REQUEST['params'];
var_dump($params);
```

Comment: var_dump($_REQUEST); shows what?

Comment: @user574632 it shows `array(0) {}`

Comment: Ok, so its a client issue, not server(php). Not an obj-c coder, but i cant see in your code where you actually make the request.

Comment: @user574632 I have added the portion of the code to the Objective C section. Thanks for wanting to help even though you are not an obj-c coder. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it after using the method of wrapping into `NSDictionary` highlighted in [this SO thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704330/afnetworking-sending-nsdictionary-as-single-array-values-instead-of-sending-them) In additional, I set the parameter encoding to `AFFormURLParameterEncoding` instead of `AFJSONParameterEncoding`. Not sure if this is even closed to the correct way of doing this but it worked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First in your OBJ-C part create a NSMutableArray with your parameters (I do it like this):

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getNumbers
{   
    NSMutableArray * tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"key",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]];

[tempArray addObject:dict];
}

return tempArray;
}

NSDictionary * paramDict = @{
                              @"action"        : @"updatePedido",
                              @"array"         : [self getNumbers],
                             };
```

and call it like this

```
NSArray *info = @[paramDict];
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:info options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"teste.php"]];
    // Create request body
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    // Append of the body with your data
    [body appendData:jsonData];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    // Set request method POST
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    // Set request Headers
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:request.URL];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
        NSError *error;

        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"response String %@",responseString);
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
     }];
    [operation start];
```

and in the server PHP side :

```
<?php
 header("Content-type: application/json");
    $data     = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $result = json_decode($data);

foreach ($result as $obj)
{
    $array = $obj->array;
}

for($j = 0; $j < count($array); $j++)
{
   $number = $array[$j]->key;
   echo $number;
}

?>
```

Just to say im using AFNetworking 2.0, wich i would advice you to consider upgrading it.